# Why won't this super simple jQuery work?

Tags: jquery

```
<style type="text/css">
    #box { background: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; color: #fff; line-height: 100px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $('a#clickMe').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#box').css('position', 'absolute').animate({
                'left' : '+=100px'
            }, function() {

                    if ($('#box').offset().left > $(document).width()) {
                        alert('that is far enough')
                    }

            });

        });
    });
</script>

<a href="" id="clickMe">Click Me</a>

<div id="box">I Move!</div>
```

I'm trying to alert "that is far enough" when the box reaches the end of the page. But the alert never shows.

### EDIT

Never mind, figured it out. I had to use $(window).width() instead of $(document).width();

Comment: Actually, if you use `document.width` it works as is. (Though I'd still add a semi-colon to the end of the `alert()` line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because moving the element to the left is expanding the width of the document.

Try adding this css:

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#box{ 
    background:orange;
    top:0;left:0;
}
```

---

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="" id="clickMe">Click Me</a>

    <div id="box">I Move!</div>
</div>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/UhgM5/1/

---

**EDIT:** Updated to make it FF compatible. Thanks to [@Tomalak Geret'kal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/tomalak-geretkal).

Comment: ahh makes sense. Already solved the issue a different way but it's nice to have an explanation why it wasn't working before.

Comment: @Montgamery: Please post your solution and accept _that_ as the answer.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: You're right. Looks like FF doesn't like `overflow:hidden` on the `body` (or something), and I needed to initialize the `top` CSS property on the `#box`. Here's an updated version. http://jsfiddle.net/UhgM5/1/ Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @patrickdw: Now the `<div>` moves upwards to the top of the document on the first click.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Yes, but that is beyond the scope of the question. The purpose of the answer was to explain why the `alert()` never fired, which I did and which is why OP accepted the answer.

Comment: @patrickdw: \*shrug\* to me, it seems like a broken solution that creates more problems than it solves!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: All the solutions have some sort of issue. The `$(window).width()` solution still expands the *page*, so although the alert occurs, it does so beyond the edge of the `window`, not the page (which can be scrolled horizontally). The `offset().left + width` solution changes the intent of the code, and the `save the document's width` solution assumes the document won't be resized. But I suppose if you only want to focus on my answer, that's the price I pay for offering help on a public site.

Comment: @patrickdw: My comments on this answer have said nothing about the other answers being any more correct. In fact, you're completely right that no answer here is perfect at present. I am focusing on this answer as it was the accepted one, and thus I feel that the OP should be completely informed regarding its flaws. No need to be so defensive!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I don't mean to seem defensive. It's just that again, the simple point of the answer was to show out that the document was expanding along with the animation. I only meant for the code to show a non-expanding document, and your heads up on the FF issue was helpful. I can respect your desire for the OP to know potential issues, but suggesting it is *"a broken solution that creates more problems than it solves"* seems to go beyond that. If this answer is really that bad, I'd be happy to flag it so that a moderator can remove it since I'm unable at this point.

Comment: @patrickdw: It's not "that bad" as to be applicable for deletion; it just has the above-stated bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems:

1. offset().left is (probably) not what you are looking for, but offset().left + width of the element.
2. If the element moves off the right edge of the document, the document will increase in width and so you can never be off the far edge.

Have a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/b3Pyv/). This is one option to solve this problem. The other is to save the documents width property somewhere and keep comparing to the original width, before the div element "stretches" the document element.